# Are there any keyboard shortcuts to drive Stack Overflow?

Tags: support, user-interface, keyboard-shortcuts

Is it possible to operate Stack Overflow with keyboard shortcuts, without a mouse? Similar to, say, the GMail interface (where pressing <kbd>?</kbd> brings up a HUD cheat sheet)?

Specifically, the following would be useful:

- "Display new messages" (i.e. like clicking on the grey notification bar)
- Open incoming messages, and optionally scroll with cursor
- Upvote / Downvote / Close-vote / Delete-vote while viewing a question
- Jump to profile
- ,,,

Answer (score 91, accepted):

Yes.

Head over to your user profile and select preferences, you can enable them from there. Alternatively, you can [jump straight there.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/preferences/current#keyboardShortcuts)(Thanks Pokechu22)

[image: Keyboard shortcuts settings]

Once enabled, you can use <kbd>?</kbd> to bring up the help menu

[image: Help example]

Of course, the help is context aware too, so you get different options for different pages.

[image: Context aware help]

Comment: Cool! I enabled it just to +1 this without using the mouse.

Comment: It's already of FAQ....

Comment: For the record, I couldn't find any hints to the existence of this feature -- searching in the help center (for "keyboard") didn't bring it up, for example. It's a cool feature, maybe it could benefit from increased exposure...

Comment: [It's a relatively new feature](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/237166/announcement-keyboard-shortcuts-are-now-integrated-into-the-site)

Comment: Thanks for the link! Question: Can you vote to close entirely with the keyboard? I coudln't figure out how to trigger the final "vote" button.

Comment: @KerrekSB I don't have VTC privileges, so I'm not 100% sure, but if it is anything like the flag window, you can use numbers to select the radio button and hit "enter" to submit the form. Also, may be worth retagging your question from [feature-request]

Comment: @Joe: Which tag do you suggest?

Comment: Direct link to this button: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/preferences/current#keyboardShortcuts

Comment: How about an option to enable the tab key to make the SO edit box a bit more code-friendly?

Comment: @Joeytje50 using ctrl+k will indent your code for you, if that's what you're after?

Comment: @Joe well, I meant more like when you're typing a quick piece of code that you can not only indent it to format it, but also have multiple levels of indentation. If you indent everything using ctrl+k you'll have all your code starting at the same column, while enabling text-editor tabs (insert 4 spaces on tab press) would make it a lot easier to indent further levels. I understand this would disable regular tab functionality, so enabling it by default wouldn't be good, but making it a prefs option would be nice.

Comment: @Joeytje50 well, I'd recommend making a feature request, though I can't help but think it already exists. I'd do a bit of research first