# Why do hotkeys not work in search?

Tags: feature-request, keyboard-shortcuts

In the questions tab on StackOverflow I use <kbd>J</kbd> and <kbd>K</kbd> keys to move up and down between the questions. These are keyboard shortcuts specific to this site.

[This is the blog post](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2012/02/stack-exchange-keyboard-shortcuts/) showing off the user script, and [this is the meta.SE post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/237166/announcement-keyboard-shortcuts-are-now-integrated-into-the-site) announcing its integration into the website without external requirements.

When I do search and want to move through the results the same way, it doesn't work.

I think it would be handy to have the same interface for dealing with the list of questions no matter where on the site it is.

Comment: What are J-K keys?  Do you mean the actual J and K keys?  Those do nothing for me.

Comment: yeah how do you use "J" & "K" ?

Comment: No references to hotkeys, either in the Help Center or here on Meta.  I'm inclined to close this as "unclear", unless you can provide further clarification.  If this is hotkeys in some other program, you're on your own.

Comment: Yes, actual J and K keys. They move up and down in question list on stackoverflow.com. Reference is here: http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2012/02/stack-exchange-keyboard-shortcuts/

Comment: I didn't install additional scripts - they are part of the site. Here is the announcement: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/237166/announcement-keyboard-shortcuts-are-now-integrated-into-the-site

Comment: @Lexsys if you are trying to clarify your question, it is better to edit your question rather than post additional info in comments.

Comment: Well, that is a neat feature. If nothing else, glad you introduced me to this. Nice!

Comment: I just went from complete ignorance of this feature to outrage it doesn't work on search results in about 10 seconds. +1/vote to reopen.

Comment: Seems that cupcake already mentioned this on the anouncement page: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/237166/announcement-keyboard-shortcuts-are-now-integrated-into-the-site#comment777796_237166

Comment: As was recently asked, "Why Can't This Be Done?", and answered ["yeah well we axually already did it some time ago"](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/269584/are-there-any-keyboard-shortcuts-to-drive-stack-overflow) ...

Comment: @gunr Cupcake and Doorknob are not the same person. Cupcakes are hard and shiny, doorknobs are sweet and squishy. Or maybe I have that backwards…

Comment: @CodyGray, mild facepalm at my mess-up. Not sure how I got that backwards either.

Comment: So, search then select search results with J and K keys is impossible? Any update?