# What's this grey gradient doing over here?

Tags: support, design, keyboard-shortcuts

This is second time I see this paranormal activity, going on, first time I ignored. I cannot reproduce it, but, I was just formatting my answer and the window scrolled down automatically, with a grey gradient surrounding the question.

[image]

So, what's happening?

Comment: AFAIK, that happens when a specific deep-linked answer is visited, however this highlighting fades away quickly.

Comment: @Bergi Shouldn't it be yellow though?

Comment: @SantaClaus: Yellow? I always thought it was grey - maybe with a shade of red.

Answer (score 57):

This happens when you use keyboard shortcuts to select content. For example, to select the current question, I can press <kbd>u</kbd>

[image: Gradient Question]

This only happens when you have [keyboard shortcuts enabled.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/269584/are-there-any-keyboard-shortcuts-to-drive-stack-overflow/269586#269586)

Comment: Why did I not know about this feature -.- (It's _awesome!_)

Comment: Don't forget that you need to have keyboard shortcuts turned on in your preferences (and I believe they are per-site)

Answer (score 32):

It does also happen with answers, that you selected with <kbd>J</kbd> or <kbd>K</kbd>, while keyboard shortcuts are enabled, as Joe pointed out.

[image]

Comment: We must go deeper!

Comment: I was going to include this in my answer, even had a screenshot ready, but then I got distracted by something and never did it :D

Comment: @Joe damn, if you want, take mine, it isn't a complete answer anyway and was only for the lulz ;)

Comment: @Theolodis nah, it's fine. I go into more detail on the answer I linked to

Comment: Shortcutception.

Comment: We *are* in meta, after all.