# Gradient Border remains when using keyboard-shortcuts, after pressing esc

Tags: feature-request, bug, keyboard-shortcuts

[What's this grey gradient doing over here?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/272901/whats-this-grey-gradient-doing-over-here) explains what the border is, but it should go when you close the keyboard shortcuts (with <kbd>esc</kbd>).

[image: question with gradient boarder, after closing the keyboard shortcuts menu]

Comment: You need to edit in how this post looks with the border, for meta.

Comment: @Braiam do you mean *Border-ception*? Or more acurately Border-cursion....

Comment: @Braiam [just for you...](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GPcAo.png)

Comment: FWIW, selecting a different item (an answer for example) shifts the selection gradient, but it seems impossible to get rid of without refreshing. Maybe it takes 6-8 weeks to go.

Comment: @CalvT we have to go deeper